# Jenkins "Poll SCM" option enabled automatically whenever I execute the job by clicking on "Build Now" option

Tags: jenkins

We are running Jenkins 2.277.4 version.

I have configured one pipeline job and disabled 'Poll SCM' option for that job. But, whenever I execute the job by clicking on "Build Now" option, the 'Poll SCM' option is enabling automatically.

Before execute the job configuration (Poll SCM Disabled) like Below:

[image]

After I execute the job by clicking on 'Build Now' option, the 'Poll SCM' option enabled automatically(please find the screen print for the same).

[image]

NOTE: We are not changing any configuration, other than clicking on 'Build Now' Option.

Comment: Does your pipeline contains a `trigger` step with `pollSCM` ? See https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#triggers

Comment: Dis you upgrade from < 2.277.1 at all? Are your plugins all up to date? Could be an issue from [table-to-divs](https://www.jenkins.io/changelog-stable/#v2.277.1).